# Swagger POST with json body

Tags: json, swagger

I am trying to write static .json file of server response using swagger. I'm stuck with post body and do not know how to describe it. It looks pretty much similar to Grooveshark api's where you have one page and different post parameters.

So, given grooveshark example (http://developers.grooveshark.com/docs/public_api/v3/)

Page that takes queries:

```
http://api.grooveshark.com/ws3.php?sig=cd3ccc949251e0ece014d620bbf306e7
```

POST body:

```
{
  'method': 'addUserFavoriteSong',
  'parameters': {'songID': 0},
  'header': {
    'wsKey': 'key',
    'sessionID': 'sessionID'
  }
}
```

How can I describe this with swagger?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

without knowing a ton about how this API operates (such as, is "songID" the only parameter type?, I'm guessing you'd want something like this in your models section:

```
"models": {
  "FavoriteSong": {
    "id": "FavoriteSong",
    "properties": {
      "parameters": {
        "type": "Parameter"
      },
      "header": {
        "type": "Header"
      }
    }
  },
  "Parameter": {
    "id": "Parameter",
      "properties": {
        "songID": {
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int32"
        }
      }
    }  
  "Header": {
    "id": "Header",
      "properties": {
        "wsKey": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "sessionID": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the operation would take the type "FavoriteSong" as a body type:

```
"parameters": [
  {
    "name": "body",
    "description": "object to add",
    "required": true,
    "type": "FavoriteSong",
    "paramType": "body"
  }
]
```