# Swagger not matching defenition

Tags: yaml, swagger

I'm getting the error:

> 0 $refs cannot match any of the following: "*#/definitions*",
>   "*#/responses*"

When trying to use a definition like this *(simplified version)*:

```
definitions:
  Camera:
    type: object
    properties:
        ip:
          description: "device IP address"
          type: string
    required: [ip]
paths:
  /cameras:
    put:
      parameters:
        -
          $ref: "#/definitions/Camera"
```

Comment: Are you trying to send the `Camera` object in the request body? Or as a path/query/header parameter?

Comment: @Helen I want to send the `Camera` object in the body of the post request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post a json body with swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411628/post-a-json-body-with-swagger), [How to create swagger yaml for post body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390806/how-to-create-swagger-yaml-for-post-body) and [Swagger POST with json body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892998/swagger-post-with-json-body). More info: [Describing Request Body](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-request-body/).